# How to determine whether String is made up only of numerical characters?

Tags: .net, string, numbers

What is the easiest way to check whether a `String` is made up of only of numerical characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[0-9]+$"))
    ....
```

Comment: Actually, `^\d+$` seems more correct as you talked about "numerical characters", which includes `-`, `+`, decimal separators, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh.aspx) or [`Char.IsNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y.aspx):

```
var isNumber = str.Length > 0 && str.All(c => Char.IsNumber(c));
```

(remember to add `using System.Linq;` for `Enumerable.All` or use a loop instead)

or use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) instead (or `double.TryParse` etc.):

```
bool isNumber = int.TryParse(str, out number);
```

Comment: The int.TryParse doesn't work for this question, because it returns true when the string contains a dash (negative number). So only the first solution is correct here.

Comment: @kor_: However, the question is not very clear, i'm not sure if a negative number should be considered to be not a number.

Comment: In my opinion the question was quite clear. He wanted to check whether a string consists of "only numerical characters". Maybe he wanted to validate some product ids?

Comment: @kor_: Your "maybe" indicates that it was not quite clear ;) Therefore i've added the `int/double.TryParse` at the end as additional resource.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in a few places, add an extension method to the String class.

```
namespace System
{
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public static class StringExtensionMethods()
    {
        public static bool IsNumeric(this string input)
        {
            return Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[0-9]+$");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
string myText = "123";

if (myText.IsNumeric())
{ 
    // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
[TestCase("1234567890", true)]
[TestCase("1234567890a", false)]
public void NumericTest(string s, bool isnumeric)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"^\d+$");
    Assert.AreEqual(isnumeric, regex.IsMatch(s));
}
```